# Request Response in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

in Spring MVC project, client send a request with an object serialize in it, client itself is an applet, so it doesn't expect to receive as a response a web page, but instead response with string object in it that will tell him if it was a success or fail. So what is the solution, i was thinking to use in a @Controller a  method that returns void, or method that return non existent page? (in both case I also was wondering if there even be response back to client )

Comment: Return the string from the controller method, and annotate this with `@ResponseBody`

Comment: if you use void @controller method, you can use HttpServletResponse object to return string to client. response.getWriter().print("String you would like to return");

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(HttpServletResponse response) {
        if(good){
            return "Good";
        }else{
           response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
           return "Response!";
        }
    }

have you tried something like this?

Comment: You might find this article to be helpful: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring 4:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/myurl")
    public String myMethod() {
        return "myResponse";
    }

}
```

In Spring 3:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/myurl")
    @ResponseBody
    public String myMethod() {
        return "myResponse";
    }

}
```